# Uninteded method invcation while logging out of service

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jboss

I have a little problem: when logging out of my cms, SOMEHOW the setter of one of my parameters is called and action performed. It results in http500.

To be specific: I pass the parameter from jsf page to backing (@RequestScoped) bean using:

```
<f:metadata>
<f:viewParam name="activate" value="#{myManagedBean.activate}" />
```

it uses setter, which makes changes in database:

```
public void setActivate(int num) {
    ab.changeActiveState("myString", num);
    return;
}
```

logout method is used on completely different bean, and calls simple method:

```
public String logout() {
    Object request = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    HttpServletRequest a = (HttpServletRequest) request;                
    try {
        a.logout();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        logger.info("Error while logout: " + e);
    }
    return "advert-list.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Logging out throws errors:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.el.ELException: /secure/my-list.xhtml @12,81 value="#{myManagedBean.activate}": javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:321)  org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:349) 
root cause
javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: javax.el.ELException: /secure/advert-list.xhtml @12,81 value="#{myManagedBean.activate}": javax.ejb.EJBException:
javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query
javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:848)
javax.faces.component.UIViewParameter.updateModel(UIViewParameter.java:284)
javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:730)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1109)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1109)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:1218)   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:74)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)  org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:349)
```

I have no idea what is going on and why. About that setter - it works as it should. And about logging out - from any other page in my project it doesn't throw anything and logs out current user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like as with [getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times/2090062#2090062) methods, you shouldn't be doing business logic in setter methods at all.

If you intend to perform actions on an initial request after the `<f:viewParam>` has done its job, then you should be using a `<f:event type="preRenderView">` listener method.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="activate" value="#{myManagedBean.activate}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myManagedBean.init}" />
</f:metadata>
```

with

```
private int num;

public void init() {
    if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
        ab.changeActiveState("myString", num);
    }
}

public void setActivate(int num) {
    this.num = num;
}
```

Note that this is in the upcoming JSF 2.2 to be replaced by `<f:viewAction onPostback="false">`.

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for)

Comment: I need to preform action like radio button, but on data from h:dataTable. Activating one row must disable any other active at that time.
I pass the argument via f:viewParam. Then the setter invokes action responsible for enabling specified item and disabling others.

Will <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myManagedBean.init}" /> replace the action I've done by using setter?
Oh, and apart from changing active row I have other options, like delete and other column where active row can be changed. Will that work together?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best, but working way to deal with this problem, is to add the if-statement in setter:

```
if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
    ab.changeActiveState("myString", num);
}
```

If You know any other, more politically-correct way to do it, please, let me know.

By the way - I was trying to pass the parameter in some other way, but none of them works.  read something on Mykong page ([1](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/)) and in comments I found that some of those ways don't work with request scoped beans...

[Mykong Page](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/)